# jQuery Changing the class of specific li as per JSON input

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to highlight specific months by changing the class of the 'li' in which those months reside. The 'key months' come from a JSON input for each brand.

The jQuery I'm using to address this is:

```
jQuery('.divResult table tbody tr td').each(function ($) {
      var MonthArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
      var Monthlist = '<ul class="wrapper"><li class="boxFalse cross">' + MonthArr.join('</li><li class="boxFalse cross">') + '</li></ul>';

      if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Key months') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function ($) {       
        var SelectedMonthArr = jQuery(this).text().split(',');

        for (var i = 0; i < SelectedMonthArr.length; i++){
          var SelectedMonthArrEach = SelectedMonthArr[i];
        }

        jQuery("li", Monthlist).each (function(){
          if (jQuery(this).text() == jQuery(SelectedMonthArrEach).text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('boxFalse cross').addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }  
        });

        jQuery(this).empty().append(Monthlist);
    });
  });
});
```

However, the revised class for the select months is not showing in the output.

Below is the complete working code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#selection").select2({
    width: '100%'
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var StatJSON = {
    "Samsung": {
      "Key months": "Jan,Feb,Mar"
    },
    "Apple": {
      "Key months": "Apr,May,Jun"
    },
    "Xiomi": {
      "Key months": "Jul,Aug,Sep"
    },
  };

  jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var data = [];
    jQuery("#selection").find(':selected').each(function(e) {
      var this_input = jQuery(this);
      if (this_input.is(':selected')) {
        data.push(this_input.val());
      }
    });
    $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));

    jQuery('.divResult table tbody tr td').each(function($) {
      var MonthArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
      var Monthlist = '<ul class="wrapper"><li class="boxFalse cross">' + MonthArr.join('</li><li class="boxFalse cross">') + '</li></ul>';

      if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Key months') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function($) {

        var SelectedMonthArr = jQuery(this).text().split(',');
        for (i = 0; i < SelectedMonthArr.length; i++) {
          var SelectedMonthArrEach = SelectedMonthArr[i];
        }

        jQuery("li", Monthlist).each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).text() == jQuery(SelectedMonthArrEach).text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('boxFalse cross').addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }
        });
        jQuery(this).empty().append(Monthlist);

      });
    });

  });

  function PrintTable(data) {
    var html = '<table class="compTable"><thead><tr><th>';
    if (data && data.length) {
      html += '</th>';
      jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
        html += '<th id="myHeader" class="header2">' + v + '</th>';
      });
      html += '</tr>';
      html += '<tbody>';
      jQuery.each(StatJSON[data[0]], function(k, v) {
        html += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td>';
        jQuery.each(data, function(k2, v2) {
          html += '<td>' + StatJSON[data[k2]][k] + '</td>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
      });
    } else {
      html += 'No results found</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</tbody></table>';
    return html;
  }

});
```

```css
.divResult {
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.compTable {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}

.compTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.compTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

table.compTable>tbody>tr:first-child>td:first-child {
  background-color: white;
  border-left: white;
  border-top: white;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.myHeader {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.boxTrue {
  background-color: rgb(115, 238, 43);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.boxFalse {
  background-color: rgb(247, 92, 92);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.wrapper li:before {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.wrapper li.tick:before {
  content: "\2713";
  color: darkgreen;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.wrapper li.cross:before {
  content: "\2717";
  color: crimson;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

Options:
<select id="selection" select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="Xiomi">Xiomi</option>
  <br /><br />
  <input id="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
</select>
<br /><br />
<div id="divResult" class="divResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with "Monthlist" because JQuery doesn't change the value of the variable. You can first append it and then modify it.

Also the current logic will set only the last month into "SelectedMonthArrEach".

```
var contex = jQuery(this).empty().append(Monthlist);

jQuery("li", contex).each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).text() == SelectedMonthArrEach) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('boxFalse cross').addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
    }  
});
```

Or you can change how you build the string as well.

Comment: Hi @hrench , thanks for the revert. I tried your approach and used a new variable, but I'm still getting the same result. :/ Could you please have a look and see where I'm going wrong with this? https://jsfiddle.net/m6Ltysud/

Comment: No need to append it again and the problem was with "jQuery(SelectedMonthArrEach).text()" which return empty string from string.
It is working here - https://jsfiddle.net/f1rvogLd/.